# Java Performance History

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

I wonder if there is some resource on the web where the different versions of the Sun Java VM are compared by speed.

Something like [the PyPy speed timeline](http://speed.pypy.org/timeline/) would be optimal, because I'm interested in how much progress was actually made over time.

Does anyone know of such a project?

Comment: By speed of what? The class library contains thousands of classes, and each JVM change can improve/deride the performance of specific classes/methods. So I don't think you can have a general answer to this. Are you interested in any specific part/aspect of the language or the class library?

Comment: No not the class library. I'm interested in benchmarks that show the speed improvements of the generated code by the JITC over the version history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such project.  However, you could do this yourself:

- Old versions of Java (back to 1.1) are still available for download from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html).
- The "[Benchmark Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/)" site has Java implementations of 10 benchmarks that you could use.

But be aware that general benchmarks are notorious for not being predictive of how real applications perform.  And Java benchmarking has unique problems due to things such as class loading, JIT compilation and heap sizing and tuning.

---

> <sup>Igouy comments:  *"Benchmarks are notorious for not necessarily being predictive of how real applications perform. Also real applications are not necessarily predictive of how other real applications perform. Someone did tell me that fasta, k-nucleotide, reverse-complement and regex-dna really were what they wrote at work - for them those tiny programs are "real applications"."*</sup>

<sup>I'm not saying benchmarks are never predictive.  The problem happens when someone takes a *typical* benchmark or set of benchmarks, and then use it / them to predict how a specific application (or worse, "all applications") will perform.  With this approach, it is a matter of luck whether the benchmarking makes an accurate prediction.  This is essentially what the OP is doing.</sup>

<sup>A better approach might be to pick a benchmark (or write one) that matches what the application does.  But even with this approach, the predictivity depends on *correctly* matching the key performance-related attributes of the benchmark and the real application.  And, most importantly, there is no way to know whether you have done this correctly, until after you have implemented your application ... by which time it is too late to use the prediction.</sup>

<sup>Hence, even if your benchmarking turns out to have made an accurate prediction, you cannot objectively determine *a priori* whether a prediction is likely to be accurate.</sup>

<sup>Obviously, if the "benchmark" is essentially the real application, you probably can rely on the predictions.  But clearly, that's not what the OP is trying to do.  And besides, there are still issues (like problem size scaling) that can confound the predictions if you don't take them into account.</sup>

Comment: I don't have time for that currently, so I hoped someone has done that already. Could it be that there are license issues? I once heard that MS is prohibiting benchmarking the CLR.

Comment: @Axel Gneiting - there are no such licensing issues with Java.

Comment: @Axel Gneiting - there are no such licensing issues with .Net either

Comment: Benchmarks are notorious for not *necessarily* being predictive of how real applications perform. Also real applications are not *necessarily* predictive of how other real applications perform. Someone did tell me that fasta, k-nucleotide, reverse-complement and regex-dna really were what they wrote at work - for them those tiny programs are "real applications".